# How to hide near by places in angular google map?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I would like to display only restaurants in angular google map.
Whenever user zooms in the map. It showing all places like bus stops, train station, hospital etc. I would like to show only restaurants when user zoom in.

There is no reference in the documentation https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi

Please suggest me. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks in advance. ﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can show only specific types of places, however, you can hide all *places of interest* by hiding them in your map options:

```
$scope.options = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles : [
       {
         featureType: "poi",
         stylers: [
          { visibility: "off" }
         ]   
       }
    ]
};
```

and the html

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/db324nCXzXuHVxp4DxG5?p=preview)

There is also a [map api styler](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) you could use to help set up your map options.

Comment: It is working now. Many thanks to you. map api styler helped me to hide point of interest. Thank you so much. You made my day. Cheers ;)

Comment: I can confirm this worked for agm-core library as well. This kinda sucks because this is not in their documentation and I have no idea of all the styles that are possible for it...